# PowerBI - Midnight issue

Tags: powerbi

I've a issue here:
When END_DATETIME is after midnight it causes problems.

```
COLUMN = 
VAR CheckWorkflow = IF(NOT(Table[Workflows] = "workflow"),TRUE(),FALSE()) 

VAR CheckBlankStartEnd = OR(ISBLANK(Table[START_DATETIME]),ISBLANK(Table[END_DATETIME]))

VAR StartTimeSeconds = HOUR(Table[START_DATETIME])*3600 + MINUTE(Table[START_DATETIME])*60 + SECOND(Table[START_DATETIME])
VAR StartTime = (22*3600 + 30*60)
VAR StartTimeEnd = (23*3600 + 30*60)
VAR EndTimeSeconds = HOUR(Table[END_DATETIME])*3600 + MINUTE(Table[END_DATETIME])*60 + SECOND(Table[END_DATETIME])
VAR EndTime = (30*60)

VAR CheckStartEndTime =
    AND( AND(StartTimeSeconds >= StartTime,StartTimeSeconds <= StartTimeEnd), EndTimeSeconds <= EndTime) 

VAR CheckStartTime =
    AND(StartTimeSeconds >= StartTime,StartTimeSeconds <= StartTimeEnd)
    
VAR Result = 
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        CheckWorkflow,BLANK(),
        CheckBlankStartEnd,BLANK(),
        CheckStartEndTime,"YES",
        CheckStartTime,"NO",
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN
Result
```

Would be happy if someone could help me out here.
Thank you in advance.

TABLE:

| START_DATETIME | END_DATETIME | Workflows | workflow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 9:45:09 PM | 1/1/2024 11:26:00 PM | workflow | NO |
| 1/1/2024 9:46:34 PM | 1/1/2024 11:40:23 PM | workflow2 | NO |

**SOLUTION:**

```
COLUMN = 
VAR CheckWorkflow = IF(NOT(TABLE[WORKFLOW_NAME] = "WORKFLOW1"), TRUE(), FALSE())
VAR checkBlankStartEnd = ISBLANK(TABLE[START_DATETIME]) || ISBLANK(TABLE[END_DATETIME])

VAR startTime = TIME(12, 30, 0)
VAR startTimeEnd = TIME(13, 30, 0)

VAR jobStartTime = TIMEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME])
VAR jobEndBy = DATEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME]) + TIME(0, 0, 0)

VAR endTime = IF(jobEndBy <= jobStartTime, 1, 0) + TIME(15, 0, 0)

VAR checkStartTime = startTime <= jobStartTime && jobStartTime <= startTimeEnd
VAR checkEndTime = TABLE[END_DATETIME] <= DATEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME]) + endTime

VAR result =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE(),
        checkWorkflow, BLANK(),
        checkBlankStartEnd, BLANK(),
        checkStartTime && checkEndTime, "YES",
        checkStartTime, "NO",
        BLANK()
    )

RETURN
    result
```

UPDATED TABLE (WITH YOUR SCRIPT)

| START_DATETIME | END_DATETIME | Workflows | Workflow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2024 1:00:09 PM | 1/1/2024 2:08:55 PM | workflow | YES |
| 1/1/2024 1:03:09 PM | 1/1/2024 3:40:04 PM | workflow | YES |

Last one should be NO when endTIME is set to 15:00

Comment: What is it you are needing to do with this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are wanting:
Find all jobs starting between 10:30pm and 11:30pm, and have finished before 12:30am (the next day).

You can simplify by using `TIME(...)`.

```
COLUMN = 
  // change these per requirements
  var startTime = TIME(23, 30, 0)
  var startTimeEnd = TIME(00, 30, 0)
  var endTime = TIME(02, 30, 0)

  // the rest don't need changing
  var jobStartTime = TIMEVALUE([START_DATETIME])
  var jobStartDate = DATEVALUE([START_DATETIME])

  var rangeAcrossMidnight = startTimeEnd < startTime
  var jobStartedBeforeMidnight = rangeAcrossMidnight && startTime <= jobStartTime
  var endTimeIsNextDay = endTime < startTimeEnd
  var dayAdd = IF(jobStartedBeforeMidnight || endTimeIsNextDay, 1, 0)
  var jobEndBy = jobStartDate + endTime + dayAdd

  var checkWorkflow = [Workflows] <> "workflow"
  var checkBlankStartEnd = ISBLANK([START_DATETIME]) || ISBLANK([END_DATETIME])
  var checkStartTime = IF(rangeAcrossMidnight,
      startTime <= jobStartTime || jobStartTime <= startTimeEnd,
      startTime <= jobStartTime && jobStartTime <= startTimeEnd
    )
  var checkEndTime = [END_DATETIME] <= jobEndBy

  var result = 
    SWITCH(
      TRUE(),
      checkWorkflow, BLANK(),
      checkBlankStartEnd, BLANK(),
      checkStartTime && checkEndTime, "YES",
      checkStartTime, "NO",
      BLANK()
    )

  return result
```

Comment: Hello Sam Nseir,

Thank you for taking your time to help me! 

EndTime - The job must be finished before, if it exceeds then it's breached. I'm using YES / NO as you can see here.

It varies when job starts sometimes its a bit early or late that's why I'm having range of 1h (30 mins before and 30 mins after) to catch up all these.

StartTime: Between 22.30 and 23.30
EndTime: Should be before 00:30

Comment: Thank you again, seems something is missing here. checkDuration isn't existing earlier in the code.

Comment: I have even tested with checkEndTime there but it doesnt return something at all.

Comment: Try it again, I probably made an edit after you tried.

Comment: Tried to use your code snippet like this but it doesn't work. See here: https://pastebin.com/D6dwLAFQ I am not getting any NO or YES only blanks (With my code above I'm getting multiple NO there they should be YES)

Comment: Can you provide a sample table. Add it to the question in markdown table format.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for my mistake. Forgot to fix timestamps in startTime and startTimeEnd and when I now did it, they are still shown as NO even they are within time frame according to table see in my first post. YES means it's on-time, NO then its breached.

Comment: Fixed it, answer updated. My misunderstanding that `TIME(24, 30, 0)` would add a day, it doesn't.

Comment: It's working like a charm now thank you. One last question lets say: startTime is 18:00, startTimeEnd is 19:00 and endTime is 22.00 (same day) and it excess the endTime until next day would it work with 1+ TIME(22, 00, 0) ? Or how should I do here?

Comment: Have endTime as `TIME(22, 0, 0)` without the 1 +. The `1 +` signifies the next day and that time. See `jobEndBy` which is saying the start date (without time, ie midnight) + 1 (next day) + endTime. So for this case you don't want to add a day as you want to check the same day as it stated.

Comment: Please help mark the answer as [Accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kjx.png) for the benefit of all.

Comment: Hello again, thank you very much will test everything but I think it all work as expected. Otherwise I'll come back :) Have a great day Sam!

Comment: Hello again Sam, now I'm seeing it will be a issue when it started and ended in same day. VAR endTime = 1 + TIME(15, 0, 0) // plus 1 for next day will always be next day, if it ends earlier lets say it started 13.00 and ended 15.46 it will be a problem here. How should I solve it?

Comment: This solved the problem (See last code in main post)

Comment: Or it didn't solve the issue :( The problem is that when VAR endTime is after midnight then it will be NO as result even if it ended 23:45 for example) You maybe can help here Sam?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. Can you provide a sample table in markdown format (update your question with it). The expression checks the end DATE and TIME to ensure it completes by 00:30 the following day. If you are getting NO for 23:45, then check if its end date is the same as the start date. It will be NO for 23:45 for the next day.

Comment: If you test your last script, it will not be a issue since it's next day. I'll try to explain better: Your script when it's going to next day it works, but not if it's within same day then your script will not work. That last script with some changes works partly but it is always trouble depending on these things. It needs to work in three different scenarios: 21:30/22:30 and ends 00.00 or 20:30/21:30 and ends 00:30 or starts 12:30/13:30 and ends 17:00. I'll create table with these different ones and show 3 column with different results depending on what script I use.

Comment: Check last table in my first post. I've set startTime to 12:30 and startTimEnd to 13:30, endTime to 15:00 even if it was breached it's showing as YES there. Hope you now understand me better.

Comment: `VAR endTime = TIME(15, 0, 0)
VAR jobEndBy =
    IF(
        MOD(TIMEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME]) + endTime, 1) < MOD(TIME(0, 0, 0), 1),
        DATEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME]) + 1,
        DATEVALUE(TABLE[START_DATETIME])
    ) + endTime` seems to help this. I will double check with all other workflows with different timestamps.

Comment: Not sure why you've added the `IF` statement, and you've changed the script. It is saying `YES` because it is looking at 15:00 the next day. Go back to the original script and just don't have `1 + `.

Comment: The thing is that I cannot know if it passes midnight or not. Sometimes it do.

Comment: You are setting the start and end time, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Three examples there it should work in all scenarios. #1 - startTime is 13:30 startTimeEnd is 14:30 and endTime is 17:00 (Here it should work even if it passes midnight or ends before 17:00. YES if it ends before 17:00 NO if it is after or passed midnight into next day #2 - startTime is 19:30 and startTimeEnd is 20:30 endTime is 00:00. Scenario #3 - startTime is 23:30 startTimeEnd is 00:30 endTime is 02:30

Comment: Okay, so #3 is causing you the issue as the job may start after midnight and you have the start range crossing midnight. Before I update for this, would you prefer to use job duration instead of end time, would that be easier?

Comment: #1 is causing error with your script when it's +1 day. I can remove it yes but I do not know if the job maybe will end next day. That's why I need IF or something like this. Job duration, what do you mean? endTime is when it the job should be finished.

Comment: #1 wouldn't need the 1 + day. Are you creating a column for each different start/end combo's? Explain your full scenario so we can then come up with a holistic solution.

Comment: As it is now with your script, it isn't working since +1 always add one extra day. So when workflow is finished same day and is within timeframe it says YES, but failed ones also shows as YES. I will try my best to explain the whole picture for you soon.

Comment: I've updated the script in the answer to accommodate all scenarios. You don't need to worry about the `1 +` anymore.

Comment: Finally! It now works as expected. A million thanks for everything!!

Comment: Feel free to up-vote the answer if you feel others would benefit from it.

Comment: Hello again Sam, I've a challenge for you :) Tried by myself but cannot solve it. If the workflow starts between startTime and startTimeEnd but endTime is before startTimeEnd sometimes. (For example startTime is 08:00 and startTimeEnd is 18:00 and endTime is 16:00. Scenario 1: If workflow starts after endTime it should result in third option: UNKNOWN. Scenario 2: If END_DATETIME is still empty after 100 hours it should result in fourth option: EMPTY is it achieveable?